# Field seems not to be changed, Master-Detail relationships

Tags: apex

I am working on a trigger that compares two fields across a junction object. The field is not being updated as I would expect and I suspect it has to do with the relationship.

```
 for(Client_Financial_Account_Relationship__c rel :relatedClients) {
        // if the clients last OPA date is earlier than his enrollment date update accordingly
        if(rel.Financial_Account__r.Offer_Enrollment_Date__c < rel.Customer__r.OPA_Completion_Date__c) {

            if(rel.Customer__r.OPA_Temp_Dt__c != NULL){

                rel.Customer__r.OPA_Temp_Dt__c = NULL;
                rel.Customer__r.OPA_Completion_Date__c = rel.Financial_Account__r.Offer_Enrollment_Date__c;
                clientsToUpdate.add(rel.Customer__r.Id);
                System.debug('Financial Account trigger: end of second if: opa completion data: '+rel.Customer__r.OPA_Completion_Date__c+' fa Offer enrollment date: '+rel.Financial_Account__r.Offer_Enrollment_Date__c+' name: '+rel.Customer__r.Name);
                System.debug('Customer to change: '+rel.Customer__c);
            } 

        }            
    }
```

... here when I try to print out the customer's name I get null. I add the rel.Customer__r.id to a list then query with that id to find the customer to update...

```
  List<Account> clientsWithNewOPADates = [Select Id,Name,OPA_Completion_Date__c,OPA_Temp_Dt__c from Account Where Id in :clientsToUpdate];
  System.debug('client gettting updated: '+clientsWithNewOPADates[0].Name+' opa completion date: '+clientsWithNewOPADates[0].OPA_Completion_Date__c+'opa temp date'+clientsWithNewOPADates[0].OPA_Temp_Dt__c);
  System.debug('FINANCIAL ACCOUNT TRIGGER -> size of clients to update: '+clientsWithNewOPADates.size());       
  update clientsWithNewOPADates;
```

Strangely the right client name is printed out here. Is there anything apparently wrong with my method ?

astoundingly I added `System.debug(rel.Customer__r.Id);` to the inner 'if' and the same just after the query and the Id's match exactly. But if that's the case why does the field OPA_Temp_Dt__c not show null after the query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more than one issue here (I am not sure I follow the issue with a `Name` field being `null` in one place but not another), but there's certainly a central issue right here:

```
List<Account> clientsWithNewOPADates = [<PERFORM SOQL>];
update clientsWithNewOPADates;
```

This is basically a no-op. When you query `clientsWithNewOPADates` based on the Set `clientsToUpdate`, you're no longer working with the sObject instances you already have, wherein you nulled out the field `OPA_Temp_Dt__c` and possible made other changes. Those in-memory instances just go away because you don't perform DML to persist them.

The new instances you query here, which *do* have the same Id values, represent a brand new copy sourced from the database, so when you call `update` on them, you just persist those same starting values back to Salesforce without any of your updates.

I don't see enough of your code here to make a more concrete recommendation, but I think one shift that may help you is to remember that the value of `rel.Customer__r` *is an Account*. You can do

```
List<Account> stuffToUpdate = new List<Account>();

// .... go through and made updates ...
stuffToUpdate.add(rel.Customer__r);

update stuffToUpdate;
```

`Customer__c` is an Id. `Customer__r` is an sObject. It's confusing.

One thing to note though, since you're dealing with a junction object, is that you may want to store your updates in a `Map<Id, Account>` instead of a `List<Account>`. You'd do `myMap.put(rel.Customer__c, rel.Customer__r);` and then `update myMap.values();`. This shields you from errors that arise from having more than one "copy" of the same object in your DML operation.

Comment: That's great. I had a vague sense that it was something subtle like that, you put your finger right on it though thank you !